# Blend4Webs m_trans.set_matrix does not respect linear algebra

Tags: scripting, transforms, blend4web

I tried to scale an object alongside a specific dimension with the [set_matrix](https://www.blend4web.com/api_doc/module-transform.html#.set_matrix) function from the transform module in Blend4Web.

## Phenomenon

Here is an example matrix applied by `set_matrix`

```
a 0 0 0
0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0 
0 0 0 1
```

Let `a` be 0.1

**Expectation:** It should be scaled to 0.1 on X.

**Result:** It was scaled down approximately 0.8 on X, Y and Z.

[image]

*Left is the original cube, the right is transformed with the matrix as defined above.*

then I assigned different values to `a`, and find many anomalies, the two most noticeable:

- The  transformation is not linear,
- and happens on all 3D axes. (it should be carried out only on X)

The funniest case when `a` is zero, because in this setting the transformation matrix spans only to 2 dimensions, which should collapse the cube to a square... well it makes it a slightly smaller cube, but at least it collapsed my mind to the null space.

## Reproduction

I made a self contained example in a [project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/e8qc0b99vl8ldl0/set_matrix_anomaly.zip?dl=0), you can extract it into your project folder. This reproduces what I described, the only difference that it changes 2 basis vectors to null vector instead of one.

#### Blender file

I changed two things on the default Blend4Web starter file:

- Reseted the cube transformation to  the identity. (it is translated on Z by 1 on default scene )
- turned on the physics on the cube object, so it can be transformed.

#### Code

The following code was written into the default Blend4Web JavaScript scaffolding, under the *place your code here* comment

```
var cube = m_scenes.get_object_by_name("cube");
// The cube object on default b4w scene is transformed by the identity.
var mat = m_trans.get_matrix(cube);
// Create a global function to update the cube transformation matrix
// from the inspector.
updateMatfromWindow(mat, cube);


console.log("identity: ");
mat4_pprint(mat);
mat[0] = 0;
mat[5] = 0;
console.log('collapsing to one dimension');
mat4_pprint(mat);
/**
* after this the cube should disaper. since it transformed by a matrix with a
* zero determinant.
*/
m_trans.set_matrix(cube, mat);
```

I also added some extra features for testing, so you can update the transformation matrix of the cube from the inspector, using the `updateMat(ind, val)`, function, for example:

```
updateMat(12, 1) // will translate the cube 1 unit on x.
```

and a matrix pretty printer function.

My environment:

- NixOS 17.09 “Hummingbird” (GNU/Linux)
- Blender  2.79a
- Blend4Web 17.12.0

Comment: I received an edit to this post, which changed the programming tag to scripting, which is ok, I guess... but added the python tag, which is wrong since the code in question is written in JavaScript (it runs in the browser as a web app, and NOT in Blender). So please at least check out Blend4Web before editing this post.

Comment: I saw that. I have re-edit this time with the correct tags. (We are completely removing the programming tag.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it [turned out](https://www.blend4web.com/en/forums/topic/4415/?page=1#post-21143) recent Blend4Web (17.12.0) does not support non-uniform scaling (it will be added with the next release). Which also means: its 4D matrix module does not expose the real transformation entity, which it usess at its deepest abstraction.

## General workaround:

However Blend4Web supports non-uniform scale animations exported from blender, and it is also possible to jump to a specific animation frame. So make a appropriate scale animation and wrote a code which interpolates between its frames.

## Example:

I wrote a [window-scaleresponsive input range](https://github.com/AttilaVM/blend4web-range-input) GUI element with this method, the relevant code snippet should be rather simple for someone with a basic knowledge about the Blend4Web SDK.

```
function registerSliderResize(railObj, knobObj, frameNum) {

  var etalonRatio = 16 / 9;

  function resize() {

    var ratio = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    var frameInd = Math.floor(ratio / etalonRatio * frameNum);

    if (frameInd > frameNum)
      frameInd = frameNum;
    else if (frameInd < 1)
      frameInd = 1;

    // invert frameInd
    frameInd = frameNum - frameInd;

    m_anim.apply(railObj, "rail-resize", m_anim.SLOT_0);
    m_anim.set_behavior(railObj, m_anim.AB_FINISH_STOP, m_anim.SLOT_0);
    m_anim.play(railObj, null, m_anim.SLOT_0);
    console.log(frameInd);
    m_anim.set_frame(railObj, frameInd, m_anim.SLOT_0);
    m_anim.stop(railObj, m_anim.SLOT_0);

    m_anim.apply(knobObj, "knob-resize", m_anim.SLOT_0);
    m_anim.set_behavior(railObj, m_anim.AB_FINISH_STOP, m_anim.SLOT_0);
    m_anim.play(railObj, null, m_anim.SLOT_0);
    console.log(frameInd);
    m_anim.set_frame(railObj, frameInd, m_anim.SLOT_0);
    m_anim.stop(railObj, m_anim.SLOT_0);
  };

  resize();

  window.addEventListener("resize", resize);
}
```

**The result:**

[image]

*Two non-uniformly scaled version of the same slider adapted to the window size, changed by Chromium inspector.*

### The whole project:

You can download the whole [source code](https://github.com/AttilaVM/blend4web-range-input) and the corresponding [.blend file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mpk5hcs92jvow82/slider.blend?dl%3D0).